# Why does "UserPrincipal.Current" return a GroupPrincipal

Tags: vb.net, exception, active-directory

I am attempting to get the DistinguishedName, DisplayName and a few other properties from a UserPrincipal but when I attempt:

```
Public CurrentADUser As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.Current
```

I get an Invalid Cast Exception.

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type  System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal' to type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal'.

Can someone please explain to me why this is happening so I can attempt to rectify.

Comment: What kind of program is this in? Console app? ASP.NET?

Comment: ASP.NET, and it is in VB

Comment: In ASP.NET, `UserPrincipal.Current` is the account that the website is running under. It's not the account of the person accessing the website. Is that what you want?

Comment: I don't still understand why the code.

Comment: Whoops. I don't understand why the code.

Comment: Stupid mobile. The code. "userprincipal = user principal.current" returns a group principal. It runs fine locally. But no good when online?

Comment: Check the Application Pool and which credentials it's running under.

Comment: Will do when I get back to work. Keep you posted. Thanks